# PostgreSQL : Percentage without a WHERE

Tags: sql, postgresql

i need to get a percentage but can't use the WHERE clause because it is a part of a large SQL query.

I try to do this :

```
select (count(sector='Rurality'))/(count(sector))*100 as test from study
```

But the first count get full results instead of filtering.

In other words, this doesn't work :

```
select COUNT(sector='Rurality') AS test FROM study;
```

Maybe somebody could have any idea ? The problem is that filters are glued to the SQL query after all of this but **can't add a WHERE sector="rurality".**

Comment: yes, use a `CASE` expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach works with `sum()`:

```
select sum((sector='Rurality')::int)::dec / count(sector)*100 as test from study
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what [`FILTER`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES) is for:

```
select count(*) filter (where sector = 'Rurality') test from study;
```

For older PostgreSQL, you can use the [`CASE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html) construct, but don't forget to omit the `ELSE` clause to not count `NULL` values:

```
select count(case sector when 'Rurality' then 1 end) test from study;
```

Also, `bigint` / `bigint` will be `bigint`, so use casts and/or parenthesis, or just re-structure your formula, like:

```
select 100.0 * count(*) filter (where sector = 'Rurality') / count(sector) test
from   study;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CASE` statement inside the `COUNT`.

```
SELECT (COUNT(CASE WHEN sector = 'Rurality' THEN 1 END)) / (COUNT(sector)) * 100 AS test 
FROM study
```

Comment: Thank you a lot ! I'm trying now

Comment: @Lamak I am assuming you are saying this because of the lack of `GROUP BY` or other group-able fields, but they have stated that this is part of a larger query.

Comment: @Matt no, it's because `COUNT` will count the value 1 and 0

Comment: `COUNT(CASE WHEN sector = 'Rurality' THEN 1 END)` should work fine

Comment: It is working like this : SELECT (SUM(CASE WHEN sector = 'Rurality' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS test . The sum is correct
FROM studybut as soon as I try to divide by /(count(secteur)) * 100  it doesn"t work any more. So its working partially, but don't know how to get the percentage, but its already really nice ! Yes Stephen it is working, but doesn't accept the divide .

Comment: I think I'm going to calculate the percentage into the angularjs front end , its ok now Thanks a lot !